# Battery icon not showing in Ubuntu Unity 14.04?

Tags: unity, indicator, panel

After I did the latest update to Ubuntu Unity 14.04, the battery status icon is suddenly not showing up anymore on the Panel. I checked the settings, it should show, but it doesn't; what can I do?

Please, explain in simple words, I come from Windows and have very little Linux experience.

Comment: Open terminal Ctrl+Alt+t, run `ps ax | grep indicator-power` then add its outputs to the question (BTW, there small "edit" button under the question)

Comment: I have the same problem. The result of execute the command: ps ax | grep indicator-power 1852 ? Ssl 0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service 4047 pts/3 S+ 0:00 grep --color=auto indicator-power

Comment: probably this will work: `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.power icon-policy 'present'`. Same trick as here: http://askubuntu.com/a/477251/72216

Comment: There isn't battery status in menu bar for me in Ubuntu 16.04 too.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was the Power manager
System Manager > Power Manager > General > System Tray Icon - Always Show Icon

Answer (score 3):

The following command worked for me:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service &disown
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by editing the `acpi` option in the boot code. Hope it works for others too.

**SOLUTION**

1. When in the GRUB press the E key to enter the boot code of the option,
2. After the penultimate line looking for a part that says `acpi = off`
3. change the value `off` to `on`
4. press `ctrl + x` to start following the orders already given and READY.

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I have edited your post. It is suggested that you formatting and proper sentences to answer the questions. Welcome