# sound indicator is missing

Tags: sound, 14.04

my sound indicator in the panel suddenly disappeared. My sound works perfectly accept that I have to run the following script to enable my built-in JBL sound in good quality. I don't if it has anything to do with it (and would be another question how to solve this issue, but it works for me) I have to run this once when reboot/login to my system to get the sound to work in good quality. Sound settings are all right. The only thing is that the indicator in the panel is missing. How can I get it back?

So here is the script I run everytime I start my system:

```
#!/bin/bash

pulseaudio -k
sudo modprobe -r snd-hda-intel
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel model=asus-model4
pulseaudio --start
```

I am using ubuntu 14.04 with unity.

Comment: what are you using ubuntu or xubuntu.

Comment: I asked you what operating system you are using ubutnu 14.04 or xubutnu 14.04.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [no-sound-icon-on-the-top-unity-panel-in-ubuntu-12-04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/486249/no-sound-icon-on-the-top-unity-panel-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: but mine has more favs and this answer has more upvotes... I would think the other one is the duplicate...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For some reason, the soundmenu seems be set to invisible. To correct, run in a terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound visible true
```

You can do it with dconf editor as well (but you would have to install it from the repositories). Open dconf editor, browse to `com > canonical > indicator > sound`,and check "visible"

[image]

Comment: yeah that was it!!

Comment: I have an additional question: The indicator is set to invisible at every system boot. Why does this happen?

Comment: @markusw That is odd, then we have to find out the process that is causing it. Is it also before you run the script you mention in your post? I have to run, will look into it tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, but It seems that pulseaudio is not running, when the system boots... maybe this is a hint.

Comment: @markusw as a temporary bandage, would an automatically run script on login be helpful? the two scripts could be combined. not a definitive & clean solution, but still practical for now?

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm I encountered a similar problem, suddenly the sound indicator disappeared. Two days before also the wifi icon left. For the Bluetooth indicator looking up the dconf Editor worked. But for the sound there is only one entry available (interested-media-players).

Comment: This worked on ubuntu 16.04 too

Comment: not worked with this answer. Anyone else faced this issue ?