# No sound icon on the top Unity panel in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: unity, panel

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I just logged in and noticed that the sound icon on the top Unity Panel is missing! How do I get it back?

Comment: No that did not work for me :(

Comment: Try opening a run window with the keyboard combination Alt+F2 and type *Unity*. Then click on the unity three gears icon to reset Unity.

Comment: dont know what that means

Comment: that did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1**

If you are on a laptop, the sound icon will disappear when you reboot with the volume on mute and it will usually return if you use the fn buttons to adjust the volume.

Another way to remedy this type of situation is to bring up your system settings to change the volume from there.

**2**

Next, check to see you have a file under "/etc/pulse/default.pa". if you do not have this file, you need to download a copy of [default.pa](http://pastebin.com/EJ2qvZvA) see the answer to this post: [How to make pulseaudio work again?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225444/how-to-make-pulseaudio-work-again) Reboot after you replace the file.

**3** **(Accepted Answer)**

**Finally**, check to see if or reinstall "indicator-sound" and "pavucontrol" and maybe the indicator applet packages as well.

Also, if I remember correctly, there should be a panel volume control in "software center" but I've never had that prob in 12.04 yet

Comment: All 3 things are okey but still no sound icon.

Comment: @Jatttt Does the audio work at all? Is the missing icon the only issue with the sound?

Comment: audio works but the sound icon disappeared

Comment: @Jatttt I can't which package on my system provides that app but check to see if or reinstall "indicator-sound" and "pavucontrol" . Maybe the indicator applet packages as well. If I remember correctly, there should be a panel volume control in "software center" but I've never had that prob in 12.04 yet.

Comment: Thank You. That worked :). Please post that as an answer and i'll accept it.