# Audio icon is missing. how can i get back?

Tags: 14.04, sound, icons

I recently upgraded to 14.04 from 12.04. doing the correction of audio, I stopped getting the audio icon itself. Now it is not shown from the top right corner(it was being shown when ubuntu instatlled). 
Also, now I am seeing only 4 icons in All settings window of Ubuntu. Audio setting icon is not there in system settings ( all settings ) window too.

Comment: Hi Sathian, what is the output of `gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.sound visible` (run in a terminal window). could it be this: `http://askubuntu.com/a/477251/72216`?

Comment: Hi Jacob, Thanks for your Answer.I ran the same. Please find the answer I got:         sathian@sathian-Lenovo-3000-G530:~$ gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.sound visible
No such schema 'com.canonical.indicator.sound'

Comment: That is odd! could you (temporarily) rename the directory `~/.config/dconf`, log out and back in and see what happens? The key is one of the default keys in 14.04. possibly your `dconf` database is corrupted. The procedure above forces to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

- Open unity menu
- Go to settings
- Select "Sound"
  [image]
- Now check "Show sound volume in the menu bar".

Comment: I am not getting 'sound' itself in my system settings screen!

Answer (score 0):

Run  this commands in a terminal:
 `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop pulseaudio`

Comment: hi Laugeo, thanks for the answer. I ran the script. the result is seen below:

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-windows-live gamine-data libtimezonemap1 libupstart1
  libvirtodbc0 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 qapt-batch signon-keyring-extension
  virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` then again the first command.