# 16.04 with Unity - Icon with sound indicator icon is gone. How to activate it?

Tags: unity, sound, 16.04, indicator

Since a few days the sound indicator icon is gone. I still have the network indicator icon, the time/calender and the user icon. But the main one with the volume controls is gone.

How to activate it?

---

```
indicator-sound is already the newest version (12.10.2+16.04.20160406-0ubuntu1).
```

`restart unity-panel-service` does not help

Comment: Make sure that the `indicator-sound` package is installed & up to date.

Comment: It is. But how to start it? There is no `indicator-sound` command.

Comment: @Witek, You don't need to start it, just install it. But if it's already installed, I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-sound`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sound indicator is missing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/477226/sound-indicator-is-missing)

Comment: ^ still works in 16.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing sound volume icon on screen top (14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483397/missing-sound-volume-icon-on-screen-top-14-04)

Comment: You can find the answer on this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/483397/missing-sound-volume-icon-on-screen-top-14-04/618154#618154

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a checkbox in the sound settings:

```
Show sound volume in the menu bar
```

This activates the sound indicator.

Comment: Not sure why this becomes "unchecked" for me, but it's happened a couple times. Screenshot here from 14.04, but it's basically same in 16.04 https://askubuntu.com/a/618154/17060