# Battery indicator missing if I insert battery while the laptop is turned off or in sleep

Tags: indicator

Battery indicator is missing  if I insert battery while the laptop is turned off. I'm using official ubuntu 14.04 with unity desktop. In system settings, the option "When the battery is present" is chosen for the "Show battery in the status bar". If I insert the battery while the laptop is on, it works. On 13.10, it worked. I clean installed 14.04. Any ideas?

Edit1: Here's the output of `ps ax | grep indicator-power-service`:

```
 2709 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service
12133 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto indicator-power-service
```

Edit2: Here's an output of `upower --dump`. The laptop is on battery and unplugged, but there's no battery indicator:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
  native-path:          AC0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              понедељак, 14. јул 2014. 10:54:51 CEST (2631 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    online:             no

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.9.23
  can-suspend:     yes
  can-hibernate:   yes
  on-battery:      no
  on-low-battery:  no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  is-docked:       no
```

Edit3: Here's output of `sudo lshw -sanitize`. I did this while the indicator was working, and the computer was plugged in. Thanks!

```
computer                  
    description: Notebook
    product: K55A (ASUS-NotebookSKU)
    vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    version: 1.0
    serial: [REMOVED]
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=K sku=ASUS-NotebookSKU uuid=[REMOVED]
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: K55A
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: [REMOVED]
       slot: MIDDLE
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: K55A.407
          date: 12/25/2012
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 6080KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cache:0
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 8
          slot: CPU Internal L2
          size: 512KiB
          capacity: 512KiB
          capabilities: internal write-through unified
     *-cache:1
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 9
          slot: CPU Internal L1
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 128KiB
          capabilities: internal write-through data
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: a
          slot: CPU Internal L3
          size: 3MiB
          capacity: 3MiB
          capabilities: internal write-back unified
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: b
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
             product: ASU1600S11-4G-EDEG
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 0
             serial: [REMOVED]
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 1
             serial: [REMOVED]
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 2
             serial: [REMOVED]
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 3
             serial: [REMOVED]
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: c
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz
          slot: SOCKET 0
          size: 1200MHz
          capacity: 3800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:45 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:40 memory:f7e00000-f7e0ffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:44 memory:f7e1a000-f7e1a00f
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7e18000-f7e183ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:46 memory:f7e10000-f7e13fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7dfffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 01
                serial: [REMOVED]
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-30-generic firmware=N/A ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d7ffff memory:f7d80000-f7d8ffff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:19 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f7c00000-f7cfffff ioport:f0000000(size=1048576)
           *-generic
                description: Unassigned class
                product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:41 memory:f7c00000-f7c0ffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0.2
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
                logical name: eth0
                version: 0a
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:42 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7e17000-f7e173ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:43 ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7e16000-f7e167ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7e15000-f7e150ff ioport:f040(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: KINGSTON SH103S3
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 526A
             serial: [REMOVED]
             size: 111GiB (120GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=d8069d3f-80ce-456e-8392-d8aa875ac53c sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0
                description: Linux swap volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: 1
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 3904MiB
                capacity: 3904MiB
                capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
           *-volume:1
                description: BIOS Boot partition
                vendor: EFI
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                serial: [REMOVED]
                capacity: 1023KiB
                capabilities: nofs
           *-volume:2
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 97GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2014-05-21 14:41:15 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2014-07-15 13:03:38 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2014-07-15 13:03:38 state=mounted
           *-volume:3
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                logical name: /boot/efi
                version: FAT32
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 198MiB
                capacity: 209MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: CDDVDW SN-208BB
             vendor: TSSTcorp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: AS02
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

Comment: what do you mean " if I insert battery while the laptop is turned off"??? so if you insert battery while its on it works?

Comment: Yes, if I insert it while it's on, it works.

Comment: Please, tell me if you need more additional information.

Comment: I once had a solution that fixed this issue, ill look for it, ill give it to you in an hour

Comment: Does it do the same when you're on different theme? It may be unrelated, but i once had disappearing time indicator after sleep resume. I changed themes and icons with Unity Tweak Tool and haven't been noticing that occurring again.

Comment: @DusanMilosevic, Have you made any kernel update before issue started?

Comment: No, this issue is here since the installation of 14.04

Comment: @DusanMilosevic, I think some thing related to kernel. battery is not detected in upower. Could you add more info about your hardware `sudo lshw -sanitize`.

Answer (score 0):

you can find it in 
power

> => show battery status => present

if that didnt workout try this 
re install indicator-power

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-power
sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

then if you have configuration editor

> com => appmenu => power => right click => present
> if you dont have
>   it

else

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

restart

Comment: This doesn't help. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Test when battery is inserted, and indicator didn't show up.

1. Check if indicator is running:

   ```
   ps ax | grep indicator-power-service
   ```
2. Well, it is running.`indicator-power` relay on `upower`, So check current status reported by upower:

   ```
   upower --dump
   ```
3. `upower`/`sudo lshw` missing BAT! So it is not detected, try downgrade the kernel:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main"
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.11.0-24-generic linux-headers-3.11.0-24-generic
   sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main"
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   Reboot, Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> → Advanced: Select the old kernel.

Comment: I perfer not to downgrade the kernel. Is there another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the icon to "always on"? See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450513/battery-icon-not-showing-in-ubuntu-unity-14-04).

If you know what to run manually to bring back the icon, you can write a script to call that upon resume of the device. I run Xubuntu, so for me there is a xfce-power-manager. Maybe it is gnome-power-manager for you?

If that brings back the icon, then a script like `/etc/pm/sleep.d/11_power` might help. 
Try something like this:

```
case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
            gnome-power-manager
            ;;
esac
```

make sure to make it executable `sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/11_power`

Answer (score 0):

Are you leaving it plugged it when you install the battery while it's off? It almost sounds to me like it's a bad battery if it doesn't register the battery being in when you initially turn the computer on.

Comment: Yes, but this happened after ubuntu 14.04 installation. Not in 13.10.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings > Power > and under "Show battery status in menu bar" make sure it is set to "When Battery is Present"

Comment: It is, and it doesn't help.